# The variable declared in for-loop of c++ is not initialised

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void selection_sort(int*,int);
void output_array(int*, int);

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    int numbers[] = { 4, 6, 8, 2, 7, 5, 0,1, 3, 9 };
    int length = 10;

    selection_sort(numbers, length);
    output_array(numbers, length);

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}

void output_array(int* start, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        std::cout << *(start + i) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void selection_sort(int* start, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int max = *start;
        int max_i = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < (length - i); j++) {
            //find out the maximum
            if (max < *(start + j)) {
                max = *(start + j);
                max_i = j;
            }
        }
        //put it at the end
        for (int k = max_i; k < (length - i -1); k++) { //The problem is HERE
            *(start + k) = *(start + k + 1);
        }
        *(start + length - i) = max;
    }
}
```

Perhaps it is a problem simple enough, but why when it comes to the last for loop, k is undefined? Is it because max_i is not a compile-time constant?
[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H1E3.png)
[Program at this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQok0.png)
This doesn't make sense to me.

When it comes to the second largest number, k behaves as expected.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What is the problem HERE? You use different terms, uninitialized then undefined. What do you mean?

Comment: @273K Every time we get to the for loop I want the variable k to be a counter, counting from max_i. But when I run it, max_i is 9, k is -858993460 and my loop supposedly counting from 9 is skipped.

Comment: What do you run? It's unclear. A variable can't run.

Comment: You'll get to know -858993460 fairly well. In hex, it is CCCCCCCC, and CC is the pattern Visual Studio's debugger writes into the stack so you can more easily detect uninitialized variables.

Comment: Please, don't use link to image, put image directly in question, or better, use textual description/logs/....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void selection_sort(int* start, int length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int max = *start;
        int max_i = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < (length - i); j++) {
            //find out the maximum
            if (max < *(start + j)) {
                max = *(start + j);
                max_i = j;
            }
        }
        //put it at the end
        for (int k = max_i; k < (length - i -1); k++) {
            *(start + k) = *(start + k + 1);
        }
        // The problem was here, you wanted to access memory that does not belong to you.
        *(start + length - i - 1) = max;
    }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is rarely a helpful answer

Comment: I explained in the comment to the code, my dear Friend.

Comment: It'd be much clearer to provide a separate more detailed explanation, the comment is easy to miss. What did you change? Why was it wrong? How was it causing the problem?

Comment: I agree, I just thought that this type of problem is not one of those global once. I mean, the same problem may not occur with other developers.

Comment: To avoid problems like this I'll put a note at the start of the Answer saying something like "Code has been annotated where it made sense to do so to explain the problem and solution."

Comment: Thank you! This solves the problem exactly. I am new to c++. Mind if I ask how did you discover this? It's hard to believe that this affected k

Comment: In your first iteration i=0 and (start + length) will be pointing to the next element to the last one in the array. You should always keep in mind that indexing starts from 0 and end at n-1, if there is n elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I have got it. `length` is 10, `max_i` is 9, `i` is 0 till 9. Your loop becomes

```
for (int k = 9; k < (10 - i -1); k++) {
    *(start + k) = *(start + k + 1);
}
```

`k < 9 - i` never gets true and the loop never runs. You have an error in the program logic.

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
*(start + length - i) = max;
```

`i` has the range `0` to `length - 1` this means the above line evaluates at the extreme values of `i` to:

```
*(start + 1) = max;
```

And:

```
*(start + length) = max;
```

This means you both never write to the first element in your array and you also write after the last element in the array. The latter means your program has undefined behaviour, in this particular case as `start` is on the stack it will likely cause other variables on the stack to be corrupted.

The correct code is:

```
*(start + length - i - 1) = max;
```

Which results in:

```
*(start) = max;
```

And:

```
*(start + length - 1) = max;
```

On an unrelated note you can also use the simpler syntax:

```
start[length - i - 1] = max;
```